# Zonal Statistics results are Null in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, null

I am relatively new to QGIS and I am having issues with Zonal Statistics. I keep receiving NULL as my results for the median. I am trying to create a map displaying the median temperature for each census tract that overlaps with the thermal imagery.

I have a raster and a census tract. My thought process was to use the Zone Statistics tool in order to calculate the median temperature. The first step I took was downloading a 2017 census tract . Next, I confirmed that it was in the same projection as the thermal raster I am using. I did this by exporting the census tract as a new shapefile and matched the CRS to the raster. Afterwards, I attempted to use the tool and received NULL results for the Median value.

So, I went back and used the fix geometry tool for the census data and reattempted to calculate the median but still received NULL values. I am not quite sure what is missing. The raster overlaps the census data and they are both in the same projection.

This is the link I got my census tract from https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2017.html  . I scrolled down to the dropdown for Census Tract and chose California.(cb_2017_06_tract_500k.) the thermal raster is located in California. I can also email the thermal raster

Comment: Did you try creating a (very simple) polygon layer manually? Does Zone Statistics run there?

Comment: When I tried that Zone Statistics worked! So, If I just create a polygon layer manually and add the same fields as the census tract would I be able to load/import the data into the new polygon? Or I would have to manually enter all the data as well?

Comment: So that means that your census tract polygons are the problem. Try finding and repairing geometry and/or topology errors with plugins Geometry Checker and Topology Checker.

Comment: I see there is a difference between Fix Geometry tool and the geometry checker plugin. It showed up with 44 errors all are polygon with holes. I will work on this. Thank you!

Comment: It's not completely the same. However,  I can't tell you the differences in detail. Have a look at the documentation

Comment: So I realized all of the errors where located in areas that the Thermal was not located in. First I tried to use the fix error options where the computer automatically fixes the error. This ended giving me more errors somehow. Then I tried to just delete the polygons. Then I tried to fix each hole. I ended up just clip the census tract to the extent of the thermal raster and I was able to successful produce median values. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you resolved your problem. So maybe you post the solution as an answer and accept it - then it can be found easier and others can upvote.